# Swift: Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm working on Parse/Facebook login that keeps giving me the following error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification", referenced from:

There are over 60+ such errors, not sure why they are appearing since this code is working in a different project.  I was copying over some code and this started happening, any advice?

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the `import` part copied to your new project as well, so does the dependencies.

When it said undefined symbols, it means the function `_FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification` can't be found while compiling, which usually means the correspond framework/SDK/library were not there.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure what caused this issue, the following solution cleared up the error messages:

Go to the main page for the app (on the navigation thing on the left click on your apps name or the top section) -> Build Settings and under Linker Flags, make sure there is nothing in your Other Linker Flags